# Concatenation of a string and a function returning a string in python

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

### I am beginner in Python. Actually I am working with tweepy and I want to post a random tweet from a text file. The function random_line('tweets.txt') fetches a random tweet but this code isn't working. That is why I need help

```
for s in twt:
   print(s.id)
   sn = s.user.screen_name
   m = "@%s"+random_line('tweets.txt') % (sn)
   api.update_status(status=m, in_reply_to_status_id = s.id)
print("Done!!!")
```

----------------------------------------------------------------..-

Specially this line is causing the error >>>>> m = "@%s"+random_line('tweets.txt') % (sn)

### How do I fix this. In the terminal it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 25, in 
    m = "@%s"+random_line('tweets.txt') % (sn)

### TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```
m = "@%s " % sn + random_line('tweets.txt')
```

What **"@%s " % sn** does is replace the part **"%s"** in the string with the contents of the variable sn. **%** is called the string interpolation operator.

After this is done, the random line is then concatenated to this result.

Comment: Yeah.. Its working... Thanks a lot....however it is fetching the same line again n again......

Comment: Not sure how your random_line works, but here's one way to make it: import random;print(random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()).strip("\n"))

Comment: for getting the random line Im using --> def random_line(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
    return random.choice(lines)
Let me try the one you have suggested

Comment: Yours is basically the same. It should work, unless you are setting the random seed to be the same every time.

Comment: Its all working right now. My bot is working as it supposed to be. Thank you man.... you are real life saver.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.